# IE navigation background issue

Tags: html, css

Finishing up my site now and had two issues now - http://harden6615.com/portfolio/index.html - I've posted the last in another post, but this other issue is with IE and my main nav. The background looks cut from the bottom and my hover does not show the proper hover colors, but shows fine in all other browsers. No clue. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use a filter to get the gradient background for IE you have to set `filter` to `none` in your hover style to get the correct background color to show.

```css
#right-nav li a:hover
{
    filter: none;
    background: #434343;
    color: #45FFE0;
}
```

Comment: great thanks that helped the hover, but not the active state so I'm guessing its a gradient issue with IE?

Comment: @Nerdysyntax - What do you mean active state? if you mean that the button should stay gray on click, then that doesn't work in other browsers either

Comment: No I mean its regular state. Sorry not active. If you go to that site in IE9 maybe it shows a broke gradient. After removing the gradient, I see now that it is a gradient problem that I am trying to fix now.

Comment: @Nerdysyntax - viewed the site in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE. They all show gradient backgrounds for the menu buttons, and then when you hover over them they all turn gray, and when you remove your cursor they all go back to the gradient background.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at it on a faulty browser of some sort. I am using my schools remote desktop connection and I think they are using IE9, but the menu nav doesn't not show the gradient properly in IE. Just two separate colors vertical.

Comment: You are correct. I looked on my laptop pc version and the gradient shows. Not sure why my remote desktop version shows a bad gradient and which version of IE it is using, but great I think it is ok.

Comment: @Nerdysyntax - yeah I'm using IE9 as well, so was probably that it didn't update correctly or something like that. Should be good as it shows perfectly when I view the site. Glad I could help :)